# Why can I compile incorrect code?

Tags: java, oop, overriding

We know that we must override `hashCode` if we override `equals`. Still it compiles if I only override `equals`. Is that better or why doesn't the compiler make a warning or similar?

Comment: Define _must_. You're expecting the compiler to do all of your bug checking for you? When does it end?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I suppose it depends on the computer if it's 64 bits or some other length.

Comment: @DacSaunders, what the java compiler compiles and doesn't compile is specified in the Java Language Specification (JLS). JLS doesn't say that you *must* override `hashCode` whenever you override `equals`. This is specified in the API (specifically the javadoc of `Object`). You could just as well say that you should never do `while (true) {}` because your program will crash. Still, the compiler will obviously compile it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers in general don't enforce semantic constrains.

In this particular case compiler will not be able to provide *reliable* warning - what if you know that base class `hashCode` works for derived class? Or if you really need just `equals`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the compiler to treat this scenario as an error if you wish.

**IntelliJ**

*Settings > Editor > Inspections > Java > Probable bugs > equals() and hashCode() not paired*

The description is,

> This inspection reports classes that override the equals() method but do not override the hashCode() method, or vice versa, which could potentially lead to problems when the class is added to a Collection.

Enable the inspection and set its severity to Error.

**Eclipse**

*Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Potential programming problems > Class overrides 'equals()' but not 'hashCode()'*